# Update a mongodb document in nestjs typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs

I am trying to update a mongodb document from my server which is written in nodejs typescript.
I am using the mongodb library (not mongoose).

```
let o = await this.getOrder(orderId)
o=o[0]
 
db.collection('orders').deleteOne({ orderId: orderId }).then(
            db.collection('orders').insertOne({ ...o, active: false, shopId: shopId })
        )
```

the getOrder function looks like this:

```
    getOrder = (orderId) => {
    let col = db.collection('orders').find({ orderId: orderId }).toArray();
    return col;
}
```

this works sometimes, but other times it crashes and says the _id is duplicated, basically my understanding is it's trying to insert before it finishes to delete. but why? I used the then keyword!

(In addition I would like to take out the await and change it to then, and also for some reason I need to do o=o[0], can anyone help me with taking it out?)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are `orderId` values unique in your collection?  If so, perhaps using `findOne` instead of `find` may be useful for you.  But maybe you really want to use `updateOne` instead chaining `deleteOne` and `insertOne`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should add `await` before query in `getOrder` function. The reason for you need `o=o[0]` because `getOrder` return array and you try get first order in that result. You can use `findOne` instead of `find`.

Secondly, I not sure about your bug, But if db have 2 record same `orderId` and you only delete one of them. One more, you try insert new document with old `_id`.

May be you only want to update order, so should use `updateOne` like:

```
//db.collection('orders').deleteOne({ orderId: orderId }).then(
//        db.collection('orders').insertOne({ ...o, active: false, shopId: shopId })
//)
db.collection('orders').updateOne({ orderId: orderId }, { $set: { active: false, shopId: shopId } });
```